# continuous maps compact set to compact set.

Tags: compactness

If $A$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$ and $f : A \to \Bbb R$ is a continuous function then prove or disprove the following.

1. If $A$ is a bounded set but not closed then $f(A)$ is bounded.
2. If $A$ is a closed set but not bounded then $f(A)$ is closed.

My Attempt : 
I have seen a result which tells that Image of closed and bounded set is closed and bounded. Will happen when one condition either closed or bounded is relaxed.

Answer (score 3):

A brief answer to settle one of the questions that Baljeet asks: in general, a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ will **not** be closed (i.e. enjoying the property of sending closed subsets to closed subsets). Here is one possible counter-example: consider any $a \in (0,1)$ and take $f$ to be the exponential function of base $a$, in other words such that

$$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \\ f(x)=a^x$$

Clearly $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a closed subset in the order topology (the standard one at work in analysis), however $f(\mathbb{N})=\{a^n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is no longer closed:
since $$a^n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$$

we infer that $0$ is a point adherent to this subset (i.e. in its closure) lying though in the complement of this subset.

A perhaps even clearer counter-example can be found in the instance of 
$$g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \\ g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$

Indeed $g([0, \infty))=(0,1]$ is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

1) Take $A=(0,\pi/2)$ Then $f(x)=\tan(x)$ is unbounded, but $A$ is bounded.

2) Take $A=\Bbb R$ then $A$ is closed (though also open) and the map $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ has $f(A)=(0,1)$ which is open.

Comment: the general idea of your counterexamples is in the right spirit, but there are bothersome errors in both your answers 1) and 2).

Comment: @ΑΘΩ oh yeah! Thank you, those are obvious errors

Comment: @Norse, Is f(A) bounded for all bounded subsets A of R ?

Comment: @Baljeet not too sure what you mean? I just gave an example where this is not true

Comment: I saw somewhere, If f : R -> R is continuous then f(A) is bounded for all bounded subsets A of R. How is it possible ?

Comment: @Baljeet Yeah, that is true

Comment: @Baljeet: that will in general be true since 1) bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are relatively compact (this means in general that they are included in a certain compact subset) 2) compactness is preserved under continuous maps and 3) compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ (or more generally a metric space) will necessarily be bounded.

Comment: @Norse, If f : R -> R is continuous function. Then f(A) is closed for all closed subsets A of R. Is it true in general ?

Comment: @Norse,Can you provide me a solution of above results in general ?

Comment: @Baljeet I think not. But I am not entirely sure

Comment: @ΑΘΩ, Can you provide me a solution or a link of the following ? – If f : R -> R is continuous function. Then f(A) is closed for all closed subsets A of R. Is it true in general ?

Comment: @Baljeet: to make things clear and explicit, let me present a full answer to this question that you pose; please refer to it below.